# Normalise Android Orientation Sensor (Roll)

Tags: android, accelerometer

I'm making an AR app similar to Google Sky Map, and need my roll value to go from -90 degrees when the handset is laying flat, to 0 degrees when the user is holding the handset perpendicular to the ground, and to +90 degrees when pointing the back of the handset (ie, the camera directly up into the sky.

My problem is that the accelerometer sensor returns values from -90 to +90, but +90 is when the handset is perpendicular to the ground. I can't simply subtract 90 from the value, because the values start to decrease as the handset starts to tilt back. So basically, I need a way of knowing when the handset has gone beyond +90?

Sorry if I haven't explained this very well, it's quite hard to get across in words.

*edit: 12/03/12*

I used this: http://www.mail-archive.com/android-beginners@googlegroups.com/msg23415.html

Comment: What do you want to do with the roll later? Anyway, I would not use [Euler angles](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5578867/341970) such as roll. You can do anything with rotation matrices that you can do with the Euler angles.

Comment: By the way, I think you mean "pitch", not "roll"

Answer (score 0):

Use Accelerometer sensor instead of Orientation sensor.  And dont  confuse, dont mix theirs.

Answer (score 0):

Value of roll will go beyond the value of +90 when the acceleration across z axis is negative. So you can use this fact and calibrate your phone accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should never use the *ORIENTATION* sensor, and you should avoid using `getOrientation()` as well. Instead, you should be using *ACCELEROMETER* or *GRAVITY* combined with *MAGNETOMETER* with `getRotationMatrix()` and using 3-d transforms for your app.

You can also use the *ROTATION* sensor which returns a Quaternion, which is easy enough to convert to a transformation matrix.

The only time you want to use *ORIENTATION* is when you're displaying numeric values in human-friendly terms.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11550241/338479 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/13895376/338479 for much more detailed answers and sample code.