# Android: Magnetometer data deviates

Tags: android, accelerometer, gyroscope, magnetometer, sensor-fusion

I am trying to estimate heading from the accelerometer, gyro and magnetometer data. I have implemented A Complementary Filter from [here](http://www.thousand-thoughts.com/2012/03/android-sensor-fusion-tutorial/).

What I am trying is that I am holding the phone in my hand and I walked 15 steps in a straight line and I am trying to estimate Euler angles as given in the link above. But when I plot the raw data, I observe that the magnetometer data deviates. Here are the images of raw sensor data.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**My question is: how do I estimate Euler angles so that they indicate I am walking in straight line.**

Answer (score 0):

Were you walking indoors, or somewhere there might be electrical or magnetic fields? Judging by the magnetometer graph, that's what's happening. If so, I'm afraid there's no solution to your problem.

Try running a compass app, or even carrying a toy compass, and then walk the same path. I bet you'll see the compass swing as you walk.

I've been environments where moving a compass three feet down a table can cause it to swing 180 degrees.

As an aside: you almost never want Euler angles. They have degenerate cases. Try to use transformation matrices or quaternions if you can.

Comment: Hello Edward, thank you for your reply. You are correct, these signals are recorded from inside the office corridor. I also read somewhere that to estimate accurate heading, first we need to estimate heading bias. The formula given was (Theta_g - Theta_m) where Theta_g and Theta_m are heading estimated from Gyro and Magnetometer respectively. How can I estimate heading from Gyro (by integrating?) and Magnetometer?

Comment: The only way to get heading is magnetometer, and you've just seen how inside a building, it's highly unreliable. Gyro only helps (when used in a Kalman or complementary filter) to smooth out the fluctuations in the magnetometer reading. Actually, to be more precise, a low-pass filter smooths out the magnetometer fluctuations and the gyro effectively replaces the responsiveness that the filter removed. Read up more on complementary filters, but the basic answer is yes, you integrate the gyro readings to get heading.

Comment: Thank you Edward. Please have a look at the results I got from a Complementary Filter and I have compared them against the results obtained from TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30573588/comparison-type-rotation-vector-with-complemenary-filter