# iOS orientation estimation and heading error

Tags: orientation, accelerometer, quaternions, magnetometer, sensor-fusion

Instead of doing my own sensor fusion, I am using the Quaternions available from iOS and converting them to Euler angles.

I walked around in a rectangle shape for few times and I observe that the shape is not as expected. I am plotting the shape by plotting the Yaw values. Please see below. It appears that the heading deviates significantly. I maintained the path while walking.

[image]

**How do I correct the Yaw values so I get correct rectangle shape.**

Comment: How do you calculate the yaw values? I have the problem to get steady values for the heading direction.

Comment: You can convert the Quaternions to Euler. It is straight forward.

Comment: Did you use just the motion sensor or also the magnetometer for your orientation calculation?