# How do I get rotation values for a single axis using Android's gyroscope?

Tags: android, gyroscope

I'm trying to get z-axis rotation values using the gyroscope in Android, I want to simply display the degrees that the phone is rotated around the z-axis on the screen. So if I'm holding the phone upright with the screen facing me, and rotate it 90 degrees to the right with the screen still facing me, I want it to show 90 degrees on the screen.

The code I have so far is pretty basic but I can't seem to find any examples of rotating only on a single axis:

I have a text view which simply prints out the data from onSensorChanged()

```
mySensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
List<Sensor> mySensors = mySensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);

if(mySensors.size() > 0){
 mySensorManager.registerListener(mySensorEventListener, mySensors.get(0), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
}

private SensorEventListener mySensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        textviewX.setText("X-Rotation: " + String.valueOf(event.values[0]));
        textviewY.setText("Y-Rotation " + String.valueOf(event.values[1]));
        textviewZ.setText("Z-Rotation " + String.valueOf(event.values[2]));
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }
};
```

The z-axis data it prints out when I rotate the phone on the z-axis just switches between 0, -0, 1, and 2, randomly as the phone rotates. Can anyone help me out here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the fact that sensors do not return purely rotational values.

You need to account for gravity and precision.

See [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html)

EDIT: I missed the fact that you need angular, not linear movement.

Manual still applies.

Comment: have a look in here as well... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13679568/using-android-gyroscope-instead-of-accelerometer-i-find-lots-of-bits-and-pieces