# Acceleration from device's coordinate system into absolute coordinate system

Tags: android, vector, accelerometer, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation

From my Android device I can read an array of linear acceleration values (in the device's coordinate system) and an array of absolute orientation values (in Earth's coordinate system). What I need is to obtain the linear acceleration values in the latter coord. system.

How can I convert them?

**EDIT** after Ali's reply in comment:

All right, so if I understand correctly, when I measure the linear acceleration, the position of the phone completely does not matter, because the readings are given in Earth's coordinate system. right?

But I just did a test where I put the phone in different positions and got acceleration in different axes. There are 3 pairs of pictures - the first ones show how I put the device (sorry for my Paint "master skill") and the second ones show readings from data provided by the linear acc. sensor:

1. device put on left side

[image: first position]
[image: first readings]

2. device lying on back

[image: second position]
[image: second readings]

3. device standing

[image]
[image]

And now - why in the third case the acceleration occurs along the Z axis (not Y) since the device position doesn't matter?

Comment: Was the phone stationary (completely still) when you made the measurements? What is on the vertical axis? What does, for example -14 mean?

Comment: during the measurements I was moving the phone very fast along the West-East axis (just as shown on those Paint drawings) to create the acceleration readings (-14 is the acceleration in m/s*s). And as shown here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174389/different-values-between-sensors-type-accelerometer-type-magnetic-field-and-type) the measurements coordinate system IS the phone's one.

Comment: OK, now I understand your experiment. I will fix my answer.

Comment: OK, it was my mistake, I am terribly sorry. I have fixed my answer. Also, I have upvoted your question.

Comment: what is the graph tool you are using?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar that's just MS Excel

Comment: how did you managed to create it? are you using any software that pickups the sensor reading and creating that charts?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar programmed to save the readings to file on the device, and just manually imported into excel. nothing fancy

Comment: @alex Oh right! thanks anyway :)

Comment: Would it be actually better to use Sensor.TYPE_GAME_ROTATION if only an absolute coordinate system is desired, neglecting the true geomagnetic north?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I finally managed to solve it! So to get **acceleration vector** in **Earth's coordinate system** you need to:

1. get rotation matrix (`float[16]` so it could be used later by `android.opengl.Matrix` class) from `SensorManager.getRotationMatrix()` (using `SENSOR.TYPE_GRAVITY` and `SENSOR.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD` sensors values as parameters),
2. use `android.opengl.Matrix.invertM()` on the rotation matrix to invert it (not transpose!),
3. use `Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION` sensor to get linear acceleration vector (in device's coord. sys.),
4. use `android.opengl.Matrix.multiplyMV()` to multiply the rotation matrix by linear acceleration vector.

And there you have it! I hope I will save some precious time for others.

Thanks for Edward Falk and Ali for hints!!

Comment: Hmm, that's odd.  I thought that the inverse of a matrix comprised entirely of rotations *is* the transpose.  I guess I need to play with this a little.

Comment: In step 4 you cannot use sensor data directly since it's length is 3 and you need length 4. Do you add a 0 or a 1 at the end, or at the start?

Comment: @NinovanHooff at the 4th position (array[3]) there should be 0 value

Comment: What exactly is your earth coordinate system? Are you referring to this one in the docs of the `Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR` here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values?

Comment: @htz I obviously mean the most common system, the one everybody uses when reading a map, for example. One unit vector pointing north, second one pointing east and the last one headed towards Earth center. The order and direction (e.g. west/east) of vectors may vary, but the point is still the same - to use this **fixed** system as a reference for position changes of other systems, e.g. mobile phone.

Comment: Your solution seems complicated. See my simple solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14963190/calculate-acceleration-in-reference-to-true-north/14988559#14988559

Comment: Except from the inversion of the RotationMatrix, the solutions are the same. Why this inversion is made in your solution @alex? I am not familiar enought with this arithmetics...

Comment: The inversion is made probably because the rotation matrix is computed according to the world axis, instead of the phone axis, as was mentioned here(http://gentlenav.googlecode.com/files/DCMDraft2.pdf). Here's a scientific paper describing the same approach in section III.A (http://www.ece.nus.edu.sg/stfpage/elesohws/PerCom_Pedestrian_Tracking.pdf)

Comment: Is a step missing? The Pedestrian article says you need to do more than just invert. It mentions something about "reversed order": "In order to obtain the acceleration values in the world coordinate system, we multiply the inverse of the corresponding rotation matrices in the reversed order (inverse pitch, inverse roll, and inverse azimuth) to the acceleration vector reported in the local coordinate system."

Comment: @alex could you post the code where you correct the linear_acceleration to world coordinates?  My sensor listener is creating a rotation matrix using the Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR and it is working great, but i can't seem to correct the linear_acceleration the way you describe.. code sample would be awesome

Comment: @alex any idea how to do this on IPHONE?

Comment: @sau it should be somewhat similar but iPhone API is totally different so... I guess you have to crack it yourself

Comment: Could you add some example-code so one sees the actual calculations? Including declaration of all variables. Thanks!

Comment: @Alex As far as I understand, this change the reference to be aligned on magnetic north and gravity. To get it align with true north, you should rotate around the Z axis by the declination. To get the declination use `GeomagneticField.getDeclination()`

Comment: Hi Alex, Can you add the code for this calculation? thanks, Eyal.

Comment: why did you use the `SENSOR.TYPE_GRAVITY` in `SensorManager.getRotationMatrix()` ? The documentation (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getRotationMatrix(float[], float[], float[], float[])) says to use the values of the `TYPE_ACCELEROMETER`

Comment: is it possible to calculate it when device has no linear acceleration nor gravity sensor?

Comment: @alex I tried to follow the steps here but I don't seem to get earth co-ordinates. Can you take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46146602/normalizing-mobile-accelerometer-x-y-z-to-earth-co-ordinates-in-javascript-not-w

Answer (score 20):

Based on @alex's answer, here is the code snippet:

```
private float[] gravityValues = null;
private float[] magneticValues = null;

 @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if ((gravityValues != null) && (magneticValues != null) 
            && (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)) {

            float[] deviceRelativeAcceleration = new float[4];
            deviceRelativeAcceleration[0] = event.values[0];
            deviceRelativeAcceleration[1] = event.values[1];
            deviceRelativeAcceleration[2] = event.values[2];
            deviceRelativeAcceleration[3] = 0;

            // Change the device relative acceleration values to earth relative values
            // X axis -> East
            // Y axis -> North Pole
            // Z axis -> Sky

            float[] R = new float[16], I = new float[16], earthAcc = new float[16];

            SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, gravityValues, magneticValues);

            float[] inv = new float[16];

            android.opengl.Matrix.invertM(inv, 0, R, 0);
            android.opengl.Matrix.multiplyMV(earthAcc, 0, inv, 0, deviceRelativeAcceleration, 0);
           Log.d("Acceleration", "Values: (" + earthAcc[0] + ", " + earthAcc[1] + ", " + earthAcc[2] + ")");                

        } else if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY) {
            gravityValues = event.values;
        } else if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
            magneticValues = event.values;
        } 
   }
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks @orak ! I have no gravitysensor type so I just used low-pass filter to get it.

Comment: I'm sorry @orak, but what is "started" variable is all about ? To control the flow? i'm not sure about it.

Comment: @Saeger you are right, it isn't needed, I probably wrote it for flow control, which I didn't need later on

Comment: @orak could you please explain what if I should do if I want to have X axis pointing towards true north and Z vertical?

Comment: @pixie just swap the x and y values ?

Answer (score 5):

[According to the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html#sensors-coords) you get the linear acceleration in the phone's coordinate system.

**You can transform any vector from the phone's coordinate system to the Earth's coordinate system by multiplying it with the rotation matrix**. You can get the rotation matrix from [getRotationMatrix()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getRotationMatrix%28float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D%29).

(Perhaps there already is a function doing this multiplication for you but I don't do Android programming and I am not familiar with its API.)

A nice tutorial on the rotation matrix is the [Direction Cosine Matrix IMU: Theory](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9rLLz1XQKmaZTlQdV81QjNoZTA) manuscript. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It seems like it should work properly, but I have no idea why it does not.. Please, have a look at my comment to Edward Falk's answer, I explained there what's still wrong.

Answer (score 1):

OK, first of all, if you're trying to do actual inertial navigation on Android, you've got your work cut out for you.  The cheap little sensor used in smart phones are just not precise enough.  Although, there has been some interesting work done on intertial navigation over small distances, such as inside a building.  There are probably papers on the subject you can dig up.  Google "Motion Interface Developers Conference" and you might find something useful -- that's a conference that Invensense put on a couple months ago.

Second, no, linear acceleration is in device coordinates, not world coordinates.  You'll have to convert yourself, which means knowing the device's 3-d orientation.

What you want to do is use a version of Android that supports the virtual sensors TYPE_GRAVITY and TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION.  You'll need a device with gyros to get reasonably accurate and precise readings.

Internally, the system combines gyros, accelerometers, and magnetometers in order to come up with true values for the device orientation.  This effectively splits the accelerometer device into its gravity and acceleration components.

So what you want to do is to set up sensor listeners for TYPE_GRAVITY, TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION, and TYPE_MAGNETOMETER.  Use the gravity and magnetometer data as inputs to SensorManager. getRotationMatrix() in order to get the rotation matrix that will transform world coordinates into device coordinates or vice versa.  In this case, you'll want the "versa" part.  That is, convert the linear acceleration input to world coordinates by multiplying them by the transpose of the orientation matrix.

Comment: I did like you said - I obtained the acceleration vector A (in Earth's coord. syst.) by multiplying rotation matrix R (from `getRotationMatrix()` provided with gravity and magnetic field data) and linear acceleration vector V (from lin. acc. sensor in device's coord. sys.) like so: **A=RV**. But I didn't get good results. I put the phone in standing position (it's Y axis up) and moved it up and down. Lin. acc. sensor should indicate movement in Y axis while the transformed vector - in Z axis. But I got [vector V](http://i.imgur.com/73FoN.jpg) and [vector A](http://i.imgur.com/1C0CE.jpg). So..?