# How to get the Android device's physical orientation in degrees.

Tags: android

I know that I have to use the class OrientationListener to get the angle from the device. I want to get the angle between -90° and 90°. I don't know how to do it.
picture on the left: 90 degree, picture in the middle: 0 degree and picture on the right: -90 degree

[image: 90 degree] 
[image: 0 degree]
[image: -90 degree]

Code

```
class OrientationListener implements SensorEventListener
{

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
    {
        angle = Math.round(event.values[2]);

        if (angle < 0)
        {
            angle = angle * -1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: use the gravity sensor.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5112135/2001247

Comment: @ElDuderino: do you have an example how to implement it?

Comment: Maybe that will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174389/different-values-between-sensors-type-accelerometer-type-magnetic-field-and-type

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code for simple 0, 90, 180 degrees.

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
```

int rotation = display.getRotation();

Surface.ROTATION_0 is 0 degrees, Surface,ROTATION_90  is 90 degrees etc.

You can also use SensorEventListener interface if you want the degrees other than 0, 90, etc:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

        float rawX = event.values[0];
    }
}
```

You'd need to get use this code to get the degrees:

```
double k = 90/9.8;
double degrees = rawX * k; // this is a rough estimate of degrees, converted from gravity
```

Comment: this is not what i'm looking for

Comment: `display.getRotation()` would return your app rotation, not physical

Comment: what if we need the physical degree ... where could we got that? @user924

Answer (score 1):

This is a working example.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    setContentView(tv);

    Display display = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    int rotation = display.getRotation();

    String rotString="";
    switch(rotation) {
    case Surface.ROTATION_0:
        rotString="portrait";
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_90:
        rotString="landscape left";
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_180:
        rotString="flipped portrait";
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_270:
        rotString="landscape right";
        break;
    }

    tv.setText(rotString);

}
```

Comment: I mean an example of my situation to get the value if i turn the device like in the picture(see my question)

Comment: Did you try out the example?

Comment: yes. but i want the degree value between -90 and 90 degree

Comment: `display.getRotation()` would return your app rotation, not physical

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but there is an OrientationEventListener() I found while trying to figure out the [rotation for a camera](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRotation%28int%29) in degrees.

```
 public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
     if (orientation == ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) return;
     android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
            new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
     android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
     orientation = (orientation + 45) / 90 * 90;
     int rotation = 0;
     if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
         rotation = (info.orientation - orientation + 360) % 360;
     } else {  // back-facing camera
         rotation = (info.orientation + orientation) % 360;
     }
     mParameters.setRotation(rotation);
 }
```

The answers here actually help me as I am not capturing the `onConfigurationChanged()` as discussed in the [Handling Runtime Changes Yourself](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange) topic in the developer guide.

I am simply going to use the `display.getRotation()` method presented by Elduderino here in `onSurfaceCreated()` of MyActivity to set the rotation of the camera appropriately. This will work as the surface gets recreated by default whenever the device orientation changes.