# Android get Device orientation

Tags: android

I would like to get actual orientation of my DEVICE. I dont want to get layout orentation like this:

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
return display.getOrientation();
```

I want to get physical device orientation. Is there any way to get that in android?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380989/how-do-i-get-the-current-orientation-activityinfo-screen-orientation-of-an-a

Comment: Try this way in this answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22456024/how-to-get-the-android-devices-physical-orientation-in-degrees][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22456024/how-to-get-the-android-devices-physical-orientation-in-degrees

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Orientation change listener

```
OrientationEventListener mOrientatinChangeListener = new OrientationEventListener(getApplicationContext(), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) {

        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
            // Here you will get the actual orientation 
        }

    };


protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // Activate the Orientation change listener
    mOrientatinChangeListener.enable();     
}
```

Note : If you are expecting a 3 dimensional orientation from gyroscope/ accellerometer then  [Using Android gyroscope instead of accelerometer. I find lots of bits and pieces, but no complete code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13679568/using-android-gyroscope-instead-of-accelerometer-i-find-lots-of-bits-and-pieces)